# PHP routing system

Tags: php, annotations, url-routing

I'm trying to create a routing system based on annotations (something like on [Recess Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/page/routing-in-recess-screencast)).

```
<?php

class MyController extends ActionController {

    /** !Route GET /hello/$firstname/$lastname **/
    public function helloAction($firstname, $lastname) {
        echo('Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname);
    }
}

?>
```

If I go to http://domain.com/hello/James/Bond I get

```
Hello James Bond
```

So I have two questions:

1) Is it a good idea? Pros and cons vs centralized routing system (like Zend Framework). Maybe I don't see problems that my arise later with this routing technique.

2) How to check for duplicate routes if there is regexp in routes

```
<?php

class MyController extends ActionController {

    /** 
     *!Route GET /test/$id = {
     *    id: [a-z0-9]
     *}
     **/
    public function testAction($id) {
        echo($id);
    }

    /** 
     *!Route GET /test/$id = {
     *    id: [0-9a-z]
     *}
     **/
    public function otherTestAction($id) {
        echo($id);
    }
}

?>
```

I get two routes: `/test/[a-z0-9]/` and `/test/[0-9a-z]/` and if i go to `http://domain.com/test/a12/` both routes are valid.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cons:

- It may be difficult to keep an overview of URL mappings of all methods in your server.
- To change a URL you have to change the source code, mapping is not separated from the application.

If the method signature and mapping are always as related as the example you might use reflection to extract the mapping where **helloAction** is picked up as **/hello** and each method argument is a subdirectory of this in the order as they're defined.

Then the annotation wouldn't need to duplicate the URL, only the fact that the method is an endpoint, something like this:

```
<?php
    class MyController extends ActionController {

        /** !endpoint(method=GET) **/
        public function helloAction($firstname, $lastname) {
            echo('Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Java annotation format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) which should be much easier to parse uniformly.

It looks something like this:

```
<?php   
class MyController extends ActionController {

    /**
       @Route(get=/hello/$firstname/$lastname)
       @OtherVal(var1=2,var2=foo)
       @OtherVal2
    **/
    public function helloAction($firstname, $lastname) {
        echo('Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname);
    }
}
?>
```

And parse your annotation out with the following regex:

```
@(?P<annotation>[A-Za-z0-9_]*)(\((?P<params>[^\)]*))?
```

And of course cache these where possible to avoid repeated parsing.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it's a good idea / Decoupling code and entry point seems pretty much used everywhere
2. Usually you don't check for it: the first one that matches wins.

Comment: wouldn't it be difficult to detect an error then are duplicate routes and you get other action executed than you actually expected?

Comment: To me this doesn't decouple code en endpoint, since the code contains the endpoint.

Comment: @thomas : usually in debugging you should be able to detect which action was executed, so it should not be a problem

Comment: @Kwebble: That's why I wrote, decoupling code and **entry point**

Answer (score 0):

Doing so is a great idea, **as long as you cache the compiled routes in production**. There is a cost associated to parsing your files when routing so you want to avoid that when not developing.

As for checking for duplicates, don't check by comparing the declaration. Simply check when routing. If two rules matches, throw a `DuplicateRouteException`. So, when routing `http://domain.com/test/a12/`, you'll see that both routes are valid and throw the exception.

Comment: I don't think that checking for duplicate routes when routing is a good idea, because when it is hard to test for all routes and in production mode users shouldn't see `DuplicateRouteException`.

Comment: @Tomas: That's the only possible way of testing for duplicates in the case of regular expressions `/test/[0-9]+` and `/test/[a-z]*[0-9]+` are two different non-equivalent regular expressions that can lead to duplicates route. In production, your error handler can just route the traffic to an error page (`"Oups, something went wrong."`). Log the exception.